# Get element names

Tags: sql-server

I got 4 tables as follows:

```
tbProjekt
--------------
Id
```

every Machine has ProjektId which belongs to:

```
tblMaszyna
--------------
Id
ProjektId


tblElement
--------------
Id
Name
```

in this table i am associating elements with machines:

```
tblMaszElem
--------------
Id
IdElem
IdMach
```

I would like to take those elements - Name from tblElement which belongs to machines which belongs to specified ProjectId. So lets say for ProjectId 10 How can i achieve that?

Comment: some thing you missing dear, what is the link of tblMaszyna with other table. tbProjekt where it used. and in tblMaszElem, what is Idelem, idmach?

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.Name
from tbElement e
inner join tbMaszElem me on me.IdElem = e.Id
inner join tbMaszyna m on m.Id = me.IdMach
inner join tbProject p on p.Id = m.ProjektId
where
    p.Id = 10
```

This should do. This selects the Name column of all entries in the tbElement table which are associated to a machine that's associated to a project where the project ID is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this sample and its comment

```
select 
    te.name 
from 
    tblMaszElem tmem
inner join tblElement te on te.id = tmem.IdElem
inner join tblMaszyna tmzy on tmzy.id = tmem.IdMach
--inner join tbProjekt tp on tp.id = tmzy.ProjektId --i think this should be avoidable
where 
    tp.id = 10
```

Comment: To avoid the join, it would need to use `WHERE tmzy.ProjektId = 10` instead.